# Django website on Apache with wsgi failing

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

so i'm about to lunch my first django website , i currently have a server that has  been configured to host php websites  and i've decided to test a simple empty project to get familiar with the process

so the python version in this server is bit old (2.6) so i couldn't install latest version of django , i installed 1.6  and since it's just a test that's not important (im going to upgrade python version when my website is ready to lunch )

so i've installed django and created a new project called testing in this dire

```
/home/sdfds34fre/public_html/
```

which you can see using this domain

http://novadmin20.com

and after reading documentation on django (unfortunately they have removed doc for 1.6 and i had to use [1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode)) and wsgi i've updated my httpd.conf like this

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
    ServerName 111.111.111.111
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin somemeail@gmail.com
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /home/sdfds34fre/public_html/testing/testing>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>


    WSGIDaemonProcess testing python-path=/home/sdfds34fre/public_html/testing:/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/
    WSGIProcessGroup testing
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sdfds34fre/public_html/testing/testing/wsgi.py


</VirtualHost>
```

but even after restarting httpd service when i go to

```
http://novadmin20.com/testing/
```

all i see is directory list , am i missing something ?

here is my wsgi.py file

```
"""
WSGI config for testing project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testing.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: What Linux distro are you using, and do you have root access? If you're on CentOS 6 (Python 2.6), it would be fairly easy to install an alternate version of Python that is more current, and compile mod_wsgi against it. I've got step-by-step directions, so if you can, let me know.

Comment: @FlipperPA thanx this server was centos 6  but i have ordered a new server with centos 7 for this website  ...  i'm not sure what version of python would come with centos 7

Comment: CentOS 7 ships with Python 2.7.5 as the system Python. I would recommend not running Django on the system; it is always best to use a virtualenv. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DocumentRoot` directive is the main root of your problem. ([ref](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot))

try this config:

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111*:80>
 ServerName novadmin20.com

 WSGIDaemonProcess testing python-path=/home/sdfds34fre/public_html/testing:/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/
 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sdfds34fre/public_html/testing/testing/wsgi.py

  <Directory /home/sdfds34fre/public_html/testing/testing>
     <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Require all granted
      WSGIProcessGroup testing
    </Files>
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```